# Alternative form for Modulo Operation in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-arithmetic

There is a way to compute the mod operation, without using DIV or IDIV in assembly x86 language?

For instance, one could use DIV in order to take the remainder of the division. But, instead to use DIV, there are other options?

Comment: Yes, but which are good depend on the situation. Is there more context to this question or is it more theoretical?

Comment: Yes, is for an exercise @harold . 8-bits value divided by 8-bits value.

Comment: I wonder why you don't see basic-math naive inefficient way (you would mention it in question, right?): `while (divisor <= number) number -= divisor;` will reduce `number` to `0` - `divisor-1` range, which means it will be "remainder" (needs of course initial validation of values for corner cases). Which should be easy to code in ASM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can always write the division algorithm yourself, completly not using the `DIV` or `IDIV` instructions.
- There's of course a range of modulo's where you basically just need an `AND` instruction:

  ```
  and eax, 255    ;Gives modulo 256
  and eax, 15     ;Gives modulo 16
  ```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was searching for! Maybe, the use of the bit-wise AND works better in terms of performances. Is it right?

Comment: There's not much that can beat a single `and` instruction in terms of performance.

Comment: @GiuseppeCanto: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat/40355466#40355466 to learn how much slower DIV is than SHR or AND when the divisor or modulus is a power of 2.  It's at least 20 to 30 times faster.